# Banach algebra with a chain of ideals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Is there any identification of non-simple Banach algebra that it has only  one infinite chain of closed two sided ideals?

Comment: For various Banach spaces E, such as Hilbert space, the algebra B(E) has exactly three closed 2-sided ideals: {0}, K(E), and B(E). However, things can get much more complicated even for "nice" Banach spaces; see work of various people, including my colleague N. Laustsen

Comment: To those voting to close: I think the *intended* question, which is presumably asking for longer chains of ideals, is actually quite interesting, and I would like to have a go answering a revised version of the question. In particular I think there should be commutative unital infinite-dimensional answers, but I would need to look up some details

Comment: One very interesting result, due to M. Tarbard, Is that for every $k>3$ is a Banach space $E$ s.t. $B(E)$ has exactly $k$ closed ideals and these ideals form a chain. See  MR2927806 
Tarbard, Matthew(4-OX)
Hereditarily indecomposable, separable ℒ∞ Banach spaces with ℓ1 dual having few but not very few operators. (English summary) 
J. Lond. Math. Soc. (2) 85 (2012), no. 3, 737–764. 
46B20

Comment: If this question gets re-opened, I suggest that @BillJohnson leaves the reference to Tarbard's paper as an answer. IIRC, there are also some examples, due I think to Domar, of commutative radical Banach algebras in which the lattice of ideals is isomorphic to (N, max)

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Thanks. Can you give me more details of the Domar 's book (article)?

Comment: I have consulted the book of Dales and you can find Domar's result as Theorem 4.6.28. The original article was: Y. Domar, On the unicellularity of $l_p(w)$. Monatsh. Math. 103 (1987), no. 2, 103--113; see page 108.

Comment: @YemonChoi: Your first comment should say *separable* Hilbert space in order for the claim that $K(E)$ is the only non-trivial ideal in $B(E)$ to be true. Indeed, for $\Gamma$ an infinite set and $E=c_0(\Gamma)$ or $E=\ell_p(\Gamma)$, $1\leq p<\infty$, the non-trivial closed two-sided ideals in $B(E)$ are in a one-to-one order-preserving correspondence with the set of infinite cardinals $\kappa$ satisfying $\kappa\leq\vert\Gamma\vert$; this is proved in Matt Daws' PhD thesis, with the Hilbert space case (i.e., $p=2$) proved earlier and independently by Gramsch and Luft.

Comment: @PhilipBrooker Hah! You are quite right, Phil. Coincidentally I was just looking at Matt's paper on this. One more reason to get the question re-opened and the comments moved to answers...